# Dataflow job on Java SDK 2.11.0 does not scale

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, autoscaling

I have a streaming job that reads from pubsub and writes to pubsub, doing some basic processing in the middle.
When working on SDK 2.5.0, and executing it "directly", it works as expected, and scale as needed from 1 worker to as many workers as it should.
Trying to upgrade to latest version, 2.11.0, and trying to use templates - it works ok, but does not scale.
Attached are both jobs' pipeline options.
Any suggestion ?  Anything that might have been changed between those 2 versions that I am missing ?
Thanks,
Shushu
[image: SDK 2.5.0 example]
[image: SDK 2.11.0 example]

**Clarification**:
Even though I set 20 workers - I only get 1.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`numWorkers` is set to 20.  As such, when the job starts, 20 workers will be allocated based on this value.

`maxNumWorkers` is also set to 20.  So, no more than 20 workers will ever be allocated.

If need the job to scale beyond the initial 20 workers, modify the `maxNumWorkers` value.

Comment: The problem is that I get only 1 worker. Always. When working with SDK 2.11.0 and templates.

Comment: Try using a smaller machine type to force resource constraints resulting in processing lag.  If there is enough lag, it should scale.